# Hibernate Criteria Return parent record that have one-to-one child record not null?

Tags: one-to-one, hibernate-criteria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate Criteria Return parent record that have one-to-one child record not null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776847/hibernate-criteria-return-parent-record-that-have-one-to-one-child-record-not-nu)

All in the title, i have two classe Parent and child related with one-to-one relation (Parent my have one child max), 
I want to create criteria that return the parent that have child isNotNull, i tryed somme think like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("child"));
```

But not work, do you have for example please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need a criteria with inner join from parent to child. Something like `session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Parent)).CreateCriteria(typeof(Child),JoinType.InnerJoin)` Look at [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) 15.4. Associations

Comment: Ok if i have understanded i have to do session.CreateCriteria(Parent.class).CreateCriteria("Child",JoinType.InnerJoin); afterthat i do criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("child"));

Comment: No. Inner join means child is not null. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join). In case of no child sql will return no results.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Sorry but it not work :-( it other result that the sql request

Comment: It hard to say without code. Unfotunatelly i don't know java. Check mappings. And look at some sql profiler what a the exact requests go to server.